# Theoretical question about finding the basis of an image.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let's say that you calculate the basis of the kernel and it spans one vector. Then let's assume the rank of the matrix is two. Normally, you would choose the columns corresponding to the pivot points of the matrix as the basis of the image. However, could they just be two linearly independent vectors that are also linearly independent from the basis of the kernel?

I ask because by the dimension theorem, any basis of the vector space (in this case 3 dimensional) consists of the direct sum of the kernel basis and image basis of a linear transformation. Assuming we can pick two arbitrary linearly independent vectors to the kernel as the basis of the image, then there exists a basis transformation mapping that would map those two vectors to the two column vectors, so they would still be a valid basis of the image, right?

Comment: You are misstating things. A vector in the image may very well be in the kernel or vice-versa. You really should think of the kernel and image as living in different spaces. In fact, if $f\colon V\to W$ and $W\ne V$, they *do* live in different spaces.

Comment: But if my two arbitrary vectors are linearly independent from the basis of the kernel, they live in a different space, right?

Comment: Even if $T\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$, the kernel vectors are in the domain and the image vectors are in the codomain. Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. Then what's a basis for the kernel? Is that vector also in the image? Oh, and to discuss whether certain vectors are linearly dependent or independent, they must all live in the same vector space.

Comment: Okay so the basis vector of the kernel is also a basis vector of the image. However if I just wanted to choose *any* basis of the image, would choosing two vectors linearly independent from (1,0,0) suffice?

Comment: Go back to my first comment. You should not be thinking of domain and codomain as the same space, even if they look the same. In terms of matrices, you want to work with the *row space* and the kernel; those are both subspaces of the domain. Each vector in the image is the image of a *unique* vector in the row space.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thank you.